# My computer froze while I was installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I was playing with the desktop background and also had Firefox open when my computer froze while installing 14.04.2 LTS. I have never installed neither Ubuntu nor any other OS on my computer. Should i restart the pc?

Comment: In what environment did you do this? You were playing with the background and had opened Firefox? If you did this in Ubuntu I'm not surprised it went wrong. When upgrading it is not recommended to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Restart it, if you have this problem again your computer could be a reasonably low spec one. If it freezes a lot every time you try, you need: A USB (Oh, you must have that already)
A internet connection
A large amount of time (Half an hour or so maybe)

## Now that you have the things you need...

Go to this website http://www.howtogeek.com/172987/revive-your-old-pc-the-3-best-linux-systems-for-old-computers/

Choose an operating system.
Install it onto a usb and you're done! I wish you good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer anyway im going to buy a new computer in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you haven't made any changes to the disk (installed Ubuntu to the hard drive or saved files to the USB stick) then you should be fine to just hold down the power button to restart.

However, if you've made any changes that are important, you may want to try using the [Magic SysReq Key/REISUB](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) set of keystrokes to try and sync (write) everything to disk and then reboot somewhat properly.

Basically, you'll need to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen/SysRq</kbd> and then press the following keystrokes in succession with a few seconds in between each:

- <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>I</kbd>
- <kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>U</kbd>
- <kbd>B</kbd>

Basically, this writes everything to disk, then tells the Kernel to be ready to reboot, then reboots.

If all goes correctly the computer should reboot as soon as you press <kbd>B</kbd>!

Best of Luck!

[You can read more about what those keystrokes do here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).